# How to set a look up column in sharepoint by passing the lookup value using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint

How to set a look up column in share point by passing the lookup value using CSOM Powershell?

I Have a list where i want to insert an item with a lookup value for the lookup column, how to achieve this using CSOM Power shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an item and set its lookup column via below code:

```html
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

#Mysite URL
$site = 'https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01'

#Admin User Principal Name
$admin = 'admin@abc.onmicrosoft.com'

#Get Password as secure String
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force

#Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('SeriesArticle')
$context.Load($list)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$listItemInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation 
$NewItem = $list.AddItem($listItemInfo)

$NewItem["Title"]="t001"

# create an Object[] and add FieldLookupValue instances
$lookupValueCollection = @()

$lookupValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
$lookupValue.LookupId = 4

$lookupValueCollection += $lookupValue

$lookupValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
$lookupValue.LookupId = 5

$lookupValueCollection += $lookupValue

# convert the Object[] to a FieldLookupValue[]
$mvLookup = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[]]$lookupValueCollection 
 
$item["MultiValueLookupColumnName"] = $mvLookup
$item.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

More Reference:

- https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-update-lookup-field.html

BR